# how do I chain this using observables in Angular

Tags: angular

In the `.loadEnvironment()` I want a .then type shape.  The work of the loadEnvironment needs to stay there but there is another function to call, after load environment call.

How do I get the shape of a promise when using an observable?

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {  
    console.log('ctor.BackendConnectorService', this.objectId);

    this.loadEnvironment()
    //   .then(() => {
    //     this.callNextFunction();
    //   }
  }

  private loadEnvironment(): Subscription {
    // load in the basic client side environment
    // it only has the production,token getenvironment url and the server port
    this.config = AppUtil.mapToNewObject(environment, new AppConfig);
    this.getHostResult = this.getHostInfo();

    const safeSub$ = this.http.get<ApiResult>(this.getHostResult.hostUrl).subscribe({
      next: apiResult => {
        const appConfig = AppUtil.mapToNewObject(apiResult.data, new AppConfig())
        this.config = appConfig; 
        return appConfig;
      },
      error: error => {
        console.error('There was an error!', error);
        return error;
      }
   })
   return safeSub$
  }
```

Comment: try `const data = firstValueFrom(this.http.get<..>(...));` then you would be able to `data.then(handler)` and `return data`. the type would be `Promise<ApiResult>`

Answer (score 0):

Instead **Subscription** you need to return **Promise**:

...

```
// import { map, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

...

```
private loadEnvironment(): Promise<any> {
  // don't know if you need this line?   
  // this.config = AppUtil.mapToNewObject(environment, new AppConfig);
  this.getHostResult = this.getHostInfo();

  return this.http.get<ApiResult>(this.getHostResult.hostUrl).pipe(
    map((apiResult: ApiResult) => AppUtil.mapToNewObject(apiResult.data, new AppConfig())),
    tap(config => this.config = config),
    catchError((error) => {
      console.error('There was an error!', error);
      return null;
    })).toPromise()
}
```

Comment: I do love me some promises, but I'm trying to get out of my old habits.  Wouldn't a promise here be a compromise to the pure with respect to observables?  Of course, I generally don't care about such purity but I am on a new journey to catch up to current techniques.  Good answer though.

Comment: My code is to match your requirement in the constructor, that because do it with Promise, the best practice is to return a Observable
and to do switchMap then subscribe into the constructor.

Comment: that mapToNewObject is something that I use to convert a json object into a typescript object (ergh, an object with methods).  The question i how do I avoid that.

Comment: what this does is to take a very few environment variables on the client side, then mix in more values from the http call to the server.  Otherwise, I need different builds for different environments (I think).